# Render link when not null

Tags: java, xhtml, rendered-attribute

As I 'll show up a table on a page , there are certain elements that have no value . But the elements that have a value to form a link to another page . Right now it shows nothing , neither it has value or not.

I'm new to Java and do not understand what I have written wrong in my code .

Here is my code:

```
<h:link outcome="schoolclass-detail" value="#{la.participant.schoolclass.classname}" rendered="{!la.participant.schoolclass.classname==null}">
                        <f:param name="schoolclassId" value="#{la.participant.schoolclass.id}" />
                </h:link>
```

Thanks for all help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you use JSF, 'la' is your backing bean, and you want to render your link if the variable of 'classname' is not null, I would suggest to use EL expressions rather than raw java expressions.

You can read more about EL [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

The expression of your Example

> `rendered="{!la.participant.schoolclass.classname==null}"`

could look in EL like

```
rendered="#{not (la.participant.schoolclass.classname eq null)}"
```

or

```
rendered="#{la.participant.schoolclass.classname ne null}"
```

or maybe better

```
rendered="#{not (empty la.participant.schoolclass.classname)}"
```

The `not` obviously inverts the following expression

The `eq` stands for equals and therefor is equal to java `object1.equals(object2);`, or in case of primitive types like boolean `obj1 == obj2`;

The `ne` stands for not equals. You might guess what it does...

The `empty` evaluates the following expression to be in a defined state of empty covering stuff like null, empty String ("") or array or list with no contents

Also important is the `#` in front of the statement, that you seem to have forgotten in your example. If you forget this, the value of your `rendered` attribute is treated as a String, and not some expression that should be evaluated by JSF. I think that is the main cause for your example not to work, since your expression is basically correct

Best Regards

J.Adam

Comment: Thanks, I used the last example and i got the result I wanted.